# Wrap AM & PM in equally-spaced <td>s

Tags: css, timeline, html-table

Building an area chart from scratch. I have the X axis on top and need to wrap the "AM" & "PM" qualifier for each time entry so that it is below the time in each cell. I can't change the size of the cells though. TD width is set to 4% in CSS (25 time segments in total, this keeps them equally spaced when I change window-size) and I intend to do calculations off where each cell begins & ends to determine stroke coordinates on the canvas that will go below.

So is there any way to wrap each one?

Ex:

```
12:00  1:00
  PM    PM
```

With the widths set to 4%, I am noticing that it is wrapping the ones with double-digits. I don't really want to put 0s in front of each single-digit time entry though.

Code:

```
<table id="timeline">
<tr>
    <td class="0">12:00 AM</td><td class="1">1:00 AM</td><td class="2">2:00 AM</td><td class="3">3:00 AM</td><td class="4">4:00 AM</td><td class="5">5:00 AM</td><td class="6">6:00 AM</td><td class="7">7:00 AM</td>
    <td class="8">8:00 AM</td><td class="9">9:00 AM</td><td class="10">10:00 AM</td><td class="11">11:00 AM</td><td class="12">12:00 PM</td><td class="13">1:00 PM</td><td class="14">2:00 PM</td><td class="15">3:00 PM</td>
    <td class="16">4:00 PM</td><td class="17">5:00 PM</td><td class="18">6:00 PM</td><td class="19">7:00 PM</td><td class="20">8:00 PM</td><td class="21">9:00 PM</td><td class="22">10:00 PM</td><td class="23">11:00 PM</td>
    <td class="24">12:00 AM</td>
</tr>
```

(Each td has a class because I need to call each one individually later for calculations)

Comment: I don’t think there is a way to *force* a line break inside an element without inner markup, in CSS. You can allow or disallow breaks, but not force them. Is there a reason why you can’t just add `<br>` tags to the markup?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try this before. I added breaks to each one and it seems to work, regardless of how I resize the window. Thanks Jukka. Funny you commented on this, I was actually reading a post on a different forum you made a year or so ago before I came here to post this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already a different class for every td, you could write something like

```
td:after {
    top: 20px;
    left: -25px;
    position: relative;
}

.c0:after {
   content: "PM"; 
}

.c1:after, 
.c2:after,
.c3:after {
    content: "AM";
```

}

That is, generating the AM and PM labels as pseudo elements, styled to go under the real td.

The the table is stripped from the AM / PM text:

```
<table id="timeline">
<tr>
<td class="c0">12:00</td>
<td class="c1">1:00</td>
<td class="c2">2:00</td>
```

I changed the class names so that they begin with a letter.

[Demo in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/7fwZV/)